# Modify Code - Delete a row of data referenced from a cell. Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to modify the below code, so that instead of it being fixed inside the code - it would delete a row based on a certain cell. So if H2 had "expected" it would look at the datarange and delete any row that contained expected. then if you change H2 to "completed" it would then run the script and delete all rows that contain completed etc etc. I will run it from a custom menu.

```
 function DeleteText() {
 // This Code will delete any "Donation Sub-Task" in Column A.
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('JIRA JQL QUERY - READ ONLY'), true);
 var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
 var values = rows.getValues();
 var rowsDeleted = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
 var row = values[i];
  if (row[0] == 'expected') {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
     }
   }
 };
```

As Always Thanks in Advance

Comment: Since you're using `row[0]` - are your values to check for in row A?

Comment: Ross - No, Data is not always in column A. was hoping for something like row[0,1,2,3,4,5] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Script to delete rows depending on value in cell "H2".

---

#### Script:

```
function findAndDeleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('JIRA JQL QUERY - READ ONLY');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var value = sheet.getRange('H2').getValue();
  var find = range.createTextFinder(value).findAll().reverse();
  if (find.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
      sheet.deleteRow(find[i].getRow());
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

We can use the `TextFinder` to achieve this pretty easily, it returns all of the rows that have your specific text. I use `Array.reverse()` so that the rows are deleted from the bottom upwards, otherwise you'll get rows deleted that you wanted to keep. Once we've got all of the rows we need, we can loop through them and use `.deleteRow()` to get rid of them.

---

#### References:

- [`.createTextFinder()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createTextFinder(String))
- [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- [`.deleteRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRow(Integer))

Comment: Ross - doesnt this script need me to constantly update the script with the text I want deleted ? this is what I currently have to do ( I was hoping this script will look at H2, and whatever text is there it will delete.)

Comment: @TomSawkins I've updated the script to do this now.